# RabbitMQ + Web Stomp and security

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq, stomp

RabbitMQ + Web Stomp is awesome.  However, I have some topics I would like secure as read-only or write-only.

It seems the only mechanism to secure these are with rabbitmqctl.  I can create a vhost, a user and then apply some permissions.  However, this is where then Stomp and Rabbit implementation starts to break down.

topics take form: /topic/blah in stomp, which routes to "amq.topic" in Rabbit with a routing key "blah".  It would seem there is no way to set permissions for the routing key.  Seems:

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vhost user ".*" ".*" "^amq\.topic"
```

is the best I can do, which is still "ALL" topics.  I've looked into exchanges as well, but there is no way in javascript to define these on the fly.

Am I missing something here?

Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/14/introducing-rabbitmq-web-stomp/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with RabbitMQ-WebStomp you're pretty much limited to normal RabbitMQ permissions set. It's not ideal, but you should be able to get basic permission setup right. Take a look at RabbitMQ docs:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Quickly looking at the stomp docs:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

yes, you can't set up permissions for a particular routing key. Maybe you should use the 'exchange' semantics, plus bind an exchange with a queue explicitly (ie: don't use topics):

/exchange/exchange_name[/routing_key].

Please, do ask concrete questions about RMQ permissions on rabbitmq-discuss mailing list. People there are really helpful.

Unfortunately, RMQ permission set is not enough for some more complex scenarios. In this case you may want to:

- Use STOMP only to *read* data, and publish messages only using some external AJAX interface that can speak directly to rabbit internally.
- or, don't use web-stomp plugin and write a simple bridge between SockJS and RabbitMQ manually. This gives you more flexibility but requires more work.

Comment: I did end up using an exchange.  Not ideal, mainly because it complicates deployments, but it's working.

Answer (score 8):

Try this https://github.com/simonmacmullen/rabbitmq-auth-backend-http
It's much more flexible.
Basically it's small auth plugin for rabbit that delegates ACL decisions to a script over http (of which you have total control) which only has to reply with "allow" or "deny"